# Isomorphism of projective general linear group and the general linear group modulo its center

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I want to prove that $PGL(n,q)\cong GL(n,q)/Z(GL(n,q))$. (This is actually the usual definition for PGL if we study the matter algebraically but geometrically, this only comes as a theorem, as I have seen in many books.)

My plan of attack (which I am not yet sure if effective) is to define a map $f:GL(n,q)\to PGL(n,q)$ and show that it is a homomorphism. After that, show that the kernel of this map is the center of $GL(n,q)$, i.e., $\ker f=Z(GL(n,q))$. Using First Isomorphism Theorem completes the proof.

Now the question is, what should be $f$?